# IntelliJ IDEA JDK configuration on Mac OS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 10. Every time when I create a new project, it is asking me to choose JDK for this project. Anyone know how I can configure it and make it easy to use?

Comment: Follow http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95789

Comment: See the [IntelliJ documentation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under).

Comment: @dimo414 That is not a correct solution. The question was about the *project* SDK. Your link talks about the JDK that the IntelliJ editor itself runs under, which is unrelated.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

If you are on Mac OS X or Ubuntu, the problem is caused by the symlinks to the JDK. File | Invalidate Caches should help. If it doesn't, specify the JDK path to the direct JDK Home folder, not a symlink.

**Invalidate Caches** menu item is available under IntelliJ IDEA **File** menu.

Direct JDK path after the recent Apple Java update is:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In IDEA you can configure the new JSDK in **File | Project Structure**, select **SDKs** on the left, then press **[+]** button, then specify the above JDK home path, you should get something like this:

[image: JDK 1.6 on Mac]

Comment: I tried the same on OS X 10.8 with IntelliJ IDEA 11.x and 12.x EAP and it does not solve the problem. I do have both Java 1.6 from Apple and Java 1.7 from Oracle but the problem is consistent with both of them.

Comment: Follow this bug, this could be the cause http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95789

Comment: the jdk path may change from version to version, to find out the path: `which java` in terminal, it prints
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` and then use `Home` dir path to input in IntelliJ idea dialog, like this `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: I had multiple SDK configs on my intellij, removing the bad configurations resolved the problem for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 17):

Just tried this **recently** and when trying to select the **JDK**... `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` appears as **empty** when opening&selecting through **IntelliJ**. Therefore i couldn't select the JDK...

I've found that to **workaround** this, when the finder windows open (pressing **[+]** JDK) just use the shortcut **Shift + CMD + G** to specify the path. (`/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk` in my case)

And voila, IntelliJ can find everything from that point on.

Answer (score 11):

The JDK path might change when you update JAVA. For Mac you should go to the following path to check the JAVA version installed.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

Next, say JDK version that you find is `jdk1.8.0_151.jdk`, the path to home directory within it is the JDK home path.

In my case it was :

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
```

You can configure it by going to `File -> Project Structure -> SDKs`.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In recent IntelliJ versions the path changed to:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
```

Answer (score -5):

On Mac IntelliJ Idea 12 has it's preferences/keymaps placed here:
./Users/viliuskraujutis/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC12/keymaps/

Comment: This doesn't help answer the original question