# IntelliJ IDEA "cannot resolve symbol" and "cannot resolve method"

Tags: intellij-idea

What are common causes for IntelliJ IDEA not being able to resolve built-in JVM types and methods? For example, when I mouse over `String` the tooltip says "Cannot resolve symbol 'String'". It's as if IntelliJ has doesn't know where the JVM is.

By the way, I am running OS X 10.6.6. Everything was working fine until I ran the system update this morning.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95789

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA JDK configuration on Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481951/intellij-idea-jdk-configuration-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Most likely JDK configuration is not valid, try to remove and add the JDK again as I've [described in the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481951/about-jdk-configuration-on-intellij-idea-10/4482827#4482827) here.

Comment: Thanks - my Java updated itself over night and the path to the JDK had become invalid

Answer (score 70):

First check if you have configured JDK correctly:

- Go to File->Project Structure -> SDKs
- your JDK home path should be something like this: 
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk.1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
- Hit Apply and then OK

Secondly check if you have provided in path in Library's section

- Go to File->Project Structure -> Libraries
- Hit the + button
- Add the path to your src folder
- Hit Apply and then OK

This should fix the problem

Comment: Second one fixed the problem for me, but why?

Comment: this also fixed my problems..and I had many "cannot resolve symbol/method" problems that appeared SUDDENLY....without any changes to the code or the library configurations..I would really appreciate an explanation to this answer to understand the source of the mistake

Comment: what's the equivalent to Libraries in the new version of intelliJ?

Comment: The second solution worked for me too. I'd be very interested to know what happens here.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem when import projects into IntelliJ.

for in my case first, **check SDK details and check you have configured JDK correctly or not**.

Go to File-> Project Structure-> platform Settings-> SDKs

Check your JDK is correct or not.

[image]

Next, I **Removed project from IntelliJ and delete all IntelliJ and IDE related files** and folder from the project folder (**.idea, .settings, .classpath, dependency-reduced-pom**). Also, delete the target folder and re-import the project.

The above solution worked in my case.

Comment: If that doesn't help, go to IntelliJ File-> Project Structure-> Project Settings-> SDKs
and change project SDK. After pressing Ok, all Java classes should be valid

Answer (score 4):

For me, I had to remove the intellij internal sdk and started to use my local sdk. When I started to use the internal, the error was gone.

[image: my sdks]

Answer (score 4):

I tried almost everything but nothing was helping with the ibm jdk 1.8. to fix this issue. then I found an article from [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-279214/Cannot-resolve-symbol-String-when-using-IBM-JDK-180](https://Cannot%20resolve%20symbol%20String) and it worked like charm!!!

so sharing original help credit goes to @Serge Barano. incase anybody needs and not able to able to resolve the issue using previous solutions like me.

according to the article answer is:

IBM JDK has a weird layout and the jar with the String class is in bin directory for some reason:

> d:\dev\ibm_sdk80\jre\bin\default\jclSC180\vm.jar

If you add it to the JDK classpath in IntelliJ IDEA, the issue should resolve:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For me, IntelliJ could autocomplete *packages*, but never seemed to admit there were actual classes at any level of the hierarchy. Neither re-choosing the SDK nor re-creating the project seemed to fix it.

What **did** fix it was to delete the per-user IDEA directory ( in my case `~/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/`) which meant losing all my other customizations... But at least it made the issue go away.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should try File | Invalidate Caches and if it doesn't help, delete IDEA system directory. Then re-import the Maven project and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, cloning repo from the remote was the easiest way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me ,

File -> project structure -> Project Language Level (11) selection worked. Local variable syntax for lambda paramters.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, right click on String then choose "Show Context Actions", it will give you option to Setup JDK, then  click always downloaded. Then the error will be gone.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by selecting a different sdk under project structure. Also, I'm using macOS. Actually, I was using openjdk-20, I selected openjdk-19 and it resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I edited the pom.xml with this:

```
<properties>
        ...
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        ...
</properties>
```

Comment: Jonnathan Weber, please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).