# Intelij - > cannot access java.lang.Object class file for java.lang.Object not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set up a new project in Intelij. It's a multimodule project, with a maven parent module, and the application server is WebSpere 9.0.5.0. The problem I encounter is when I ty to run it, I get the error `java: cannot access java.lang.Object class file for java.lang.Object not found` and then `java: cannot find symbol symbol:   class String` for every single String in the code. If I click on a String to see the problem and see the fix of Intelij, it add the `import org.apache.xpath.operations.String;`

Comment: Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/4618860/12844632 helps.

Comment: thank's but none of the answers helped

Answer (score 7):

I'd the same problem, but with Android Studio, similar anyway, try this:

In toolbar: `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and restart`

Comment: I changed the path to JDK, faced the same problem and this answer helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and in my case, invalidate caches didn't work. A colleague of mine pointed out: make sure in the definition of your SDK, the vm.jar file is included (File > Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs).

I added this file to the classpath and the red signs disappeared:

`$PATH_TO_SDK/jre/bin/default/jclSC180/vm.jar`

If this path does not exist for your SDK, find it!

`find $PATH_TO_SDK -name vm.jar`