# How do i set up IntelliJ IDEA for android applications on a MAC

Tags: android, intellij-idea, java, java-6

I see this post [How do I set up IntelliJ IDEA for Android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications) and it looks great, except I can't find the JDK on my machine (MacBook Pro)

I know I have java installed, from the command line I get this:

```
TheThing:android bryce$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_15
TheThing:android bryce$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
```

But I've tried for a while and I can't see any jdks on my machine... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [JDK Configuration question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481951/about-jdk-configuration-on-intellij-idea-10/4482827#4482827) I've replied earlier.

[See also another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications) related to setting up Android support in IDEA.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out after posting :)