# object X is not a member of package X ^

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Trying to run a Scala project on IntelliJ for the first time. It's an existing maven project which was working fine. I'm also able to build (maven clean install from IntelliJ) it correctly, but when running individual file, I'm getting errors like this:

```
Error:(4, 12) object joda is not a member of package org
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
       ^

Error:(3, 12) object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
       ^
```

Auto-import is turned on and restart IntelliJ didn't help. I'm using the following version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1
Build #IC-145.597, built on March 29, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_40-release-b132 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Comment: Did you try the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316857/maven-package-works-but-intellijs-build-fails?rq=1

Comment: @childofsoong I tried that, deleting .iml file corrupted my entire project. I had to clone it again.