# Intellij highlights members of other classes as errors, yet it compiles fine

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

For some reason my Intellij IDEA IDE started highlighting the use of anything from outside the local class as an error. It only does it for items in the packages I wrote - for example, packages like java.* do not show as errors. Even the joda-time dependency has no error highlights, it's just from my own packages. The problem only started occuring after I wrote a pom.xml for the project, so I'm assuming it has something to do with maven.

For example, the `main` of the following line is red with the error `cannot resolve symbol 'main'`:
`import main.java.com.jamobox.jamchatserver.clients.ClientReader;`

Then in instances where a class is given as a parameter, e.g.
`public void doSomething(Client c) { .. }`
and I put something like
`doSomething(new Client());`
It will highlight the value in the parameters in red saying
`doSomething(Client) cannot be applied to doSomething(main.java.com.jamobox.jamchatserver.clients.Client)`

As I said the code compiles and runs absolutely fine, its just the IDE that thinks something is wrong. I have tried pretty much all of the answers given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905896/intellij-inspection-gives-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-still-compiles-code?rq=1) similar question, but nothing seems to have worked.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

In case it helps anyone figure this out, here is my current pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jamobox.jamchatserver</groupId>
<artifactId>JamChatServer</artifactId>
<name>JamChat Server</name>
<version>0.2.1</version>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <optional>false</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
  <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.2</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.7</source>
                  <target>1.7</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When  you say "it compiles fine", you do not indicate how you are compiling? Based on what you are describing, and what I suspect the issue is, I'm assuming you are compiling via maven.

It appears as if there is some mismatch in the declared source directory and the package names. When you create a (bare-bones) java project through IDEA, it makes the source directory `{project.basedir}/src`. Notice in the project view, the `src` directory is blue indicating it is a main (i.e. production) source directory:

[image]

This is also shown in the project structure dialog:

[image]

For a maven project, the default main (i.e.production) source directory is `java` in the path `{project.basedir}/src/main/java`. There is then a corresponding test source directory `{project.basedir}/src/test/java`. IDEA marks test source directories as green folders. Finally, there are both main and test `resources` directories that are used for things like configuration files, images, etc. In IDEA 12.x `resources` directories were marked as source and test-source directories with the same color as the corresponding `java` directory. In IDEA 13 (currently in beta and to be released in December) they are marked as distinct resource directories.

[image: IDEA Project Tree]

It sounds like when you converted to maven, the `main\java` directory was added to the `src` directory and the `com` root package directory was moved to `java`, but when this happened, the package declarations where changed from  `com.jamobox...` to `main.java.com.janbobox...`. This likely happened because when you made the move, `src` was still configured as the source directory. So IDEA saw the package name change from `com.jamobox...` to `main.java.com.janbobox...` and change import statements (and likely package statements) to match.

To fix, you need to do the following:

1. Force import the maven pom using the "Reimport All Maven Projects" button [image: Reimport All Maven Projects button] in the Maven tool window (on the right side by default)

   - If the POM is not yet showing, click the add button [image: add button], navigate to the pom.xml file and add it. Then run the reimport.
2. Verify the `java` directory (and ***not*** the `src` directory) is marked as the project source as shown in the above screenshot (showing both IDEA 12.x and 13.x project trees)

   - If the proper directories are not marked, try a reimport 2 or 3 more times. If that does not fix it (it should), go into *File > Project Structure > [Modules] > [Sources Tab]* and manually configure the proper sources. Remove any extraneous ones.
3. Verify that the `com` root package directory is in `src\main\java` and not `src`
4. Search and replace any `package main.java.com` strings with `package com`
5. Search and replace any `import main.java.com` strings with `import com`

That should fix the issues. If there is still red, run *File > Invalidate Caches* and restart IDEA. If after that there are still issues, please edit your original question and add screenshots of your project tree and the *File > Project Structure > [Modules] > [Sources Tab]* dialog window.

Comment: Thank you so much, this have fixed it. Sorry for the late response to this it's been a busy week so far but this is one huge weight off my chest. Thanks again, much appreciated :)