# Intellij IDEA reports "Cannot resolve symbol" in .tml files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tapestry

Here's a problem. Intellij IDEA constantly shows "Cannot resolve symbol" errors while I'm working on a project which includes Tapestry framework. This error appears only in *.tml files. Another thing I've noticed is this error pops up very selectively. For example, IDEA recognizes `<t:if>` tag, but cannot parse `<p:else>`. I've already tried to reimport maven dependencies, [invalidate cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905931/1140313) and import the whole project again.

Comment: Which version of IDEA? Did it work before? Do you have the XSD?

Comment: IDEA version is 13.0.2. Nope, it didn't work before. If you meant the following piece of code which I have in the top of *.tml file - `<t:container xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd" xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">`, then yes I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100807) in Tapestry 5 IDEA Plugin. Unfortunately, there is no workaround at this moment (see [Issue C](https://github.com/Widen/tapestry5-idea/blob/master/idea-bugs.md) for details).