# Chrome driver with Selenium : "no suitable constructor found for RemoteWebDriver"

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use chrome driver with Selenium under java bindings. I follow these instructions : [ChromeDriver Instructions](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)

So I run ChromeDriver.exe, put this in my code `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://localhost:9515", DesiredCapabilities.chrome());` and I get this error :

```
Error:(33, 28) java: no suitable constructor found for RemoteWebDriver(java.lang.String,org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities)
    constructor org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.RemoteWebDriver(org.openqa.selenium.remote.CommandExecutor,org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.openqa.selenium.remote.CommandExecutor)
    constructor org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.RemoteWebDriver(java.net.URL,org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.net.URL)
```

How to get chrome driver to work ?

**Edit : With the other method :**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "PATH\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I get these errors :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.tests.Scrapjv.testScrapjv(Scrapjv.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
...
...
...
```

Comment: Hmm, Why you use RemoteWebDriver?? Why not use [this](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started)  approach?! If you seemply need use chrome driver in your tests, it's not necessary to use RemoteWebDriver. Moreover, seems that selenium server hasnot been started before you start using RemoteWebDriver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the compilation error, while trying your code `The constructor RemoteWebDriver(String, DesiredCapabilities) is undefined`

For Java, you could try something like this,

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Drive:"+File.separator+"chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get(url);
```

Comment: It is a replacement for // and works for all OS. look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths

Comment: well yeah I saw that you were right it launches the server and a window of google chrome but then it still throw errors :`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.example.tests.Scrapjv.testScrapjv(Scrapjv.java:54) `

Comment: Post your entire method, since opening the browser doesn't throw this error

Comment: well even when I comment out the entire method I still get the error, the program crashes as soon as the chrome window pop out.

Comment: Can you post the code? I can't tell the problem what it is without it. Since opening the browser doesn't throw any errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60432/discussion-between-wicelo-and-vignesh-paramasivam).

Comment: Hi Vignesh, I am trying to use your answer but I am getting error as "setProperty - cannot resolve symbol setProperty" am I missing anything by the way I am using IntelliJ 2016.1.2 community edition.

Comment: @user790049 This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905896/intellij-inspection-gives-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-still-compiles-code

Answer (score 1):

I have install chromedriver throw mac terminal, then add this code to java class; it work for me.

```
WebDriver driver;
@Test
public void test() throws MalformedURLException {
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new 
    java.net.URL("http://localhost:9515"), 
    DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("hello world");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer explanation about your code is missing

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new java.net.URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to describe *why* this would solve the issue. This will give the asker an additional clues what went wrong.