# Why IntelliJ IDEA doesn't see HttpClients?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, classpath, apache-commons-httpclient

I've added following into dependencies section of my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But when I add the 1st line of "Quick start guide" (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/quickstart.html):

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

IntelliJ IDEA highlights "HttpClients" and tells me:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'HttpClients'

It looks like I have mistake with configuration. What exactly is wrong? please advise how to add support for HttpClients into the project?

Thanks!

P.S. Learned a bit more, looks like "" is redundant and wrong for this case, I removed it but that didn't help: still non-compilable.

EDIT: If I put cursor to 'HttpClients' and hit "Alt-enter" the pop-up doesn't contain any class to import. See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I assumed you imported the class right?

Comment: Why did you specify test scope in the maven dependency?

Comment: Removed scope already (copy past from 'mockito' dependency). And regarding import - no, I didn't do any import. Not sure what is the proper package name and expected IntelliJ IDEA to suggest the proper one. Should I do that manually?

Comment: Trying import "import org.apache.*;" - but it is red. Looks like I should add some other libraries

Comment: Put your cursor on `HttpClients`. You should see a small blue dialog popup suggesting pressing Alt + Enter to select package to import

Comment: I've tried, it has not "Imports". I also tried to "Find JAR on web", found few other libraries, added them to pom.xml - but still no any success with compilation. New projects added are: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1; org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.1

Comment: have you tried 'Synchronize 'pom.xml'' or 'Maven > Reimport' from context menu on your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, before I resolved the problem (see an accepted answer below) I've tried to reimport, but that did not help

Comment: There is a floating button says `Load Maven Changes` on top right of window or simply shortcut `cmd`+`shift`+`i`, this would load dependency changes to work with IntelliJ, this could also help resolving those already resolved yet **red** dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like my IntelliJ had issues with caching, cleaning cache with following re-importing of the project helped.

I found tips on that here: [IntelliJ inspection gives "Cannot resolve symbol" but still compiles code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905896/intellij-inspection-gives-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-still-compiles-code)

P.S. Though few other project were broken as a result of this action. Looks like I need to keep learning :)

Answer (score 1):

Download the jar file from
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/source-code

Extract the .jar file name httpclient-4.5.6.jar. Form a directry name lib under your project and import this .jar file to it. Right click your .jar file and click addtolibrary.