# can not resolve symbol after import the correct package in intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I want to use the `when()` method in `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`, when I go ahead, it turns out to be like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frWNh.png)

I have tried things like 
[IntelliJ inspection gives "Cannot resolve symbol" but still compiles code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905896/intellij-inspection-gives-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-still-compiles-code)
but it just doesn't work, what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

`when()` is inside `the org.apache.spark.sql.functions`

So you need to `import` the functions as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when
```