# Confused about the warning "Cannot resolve variable"

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

In *login.java* I am using `req.setAttribute("username", req.getParameter("username"));` and in *welcome.jsp* I am using `Hello ${username}` but Intellij gives me the warning:

> Cannot resolve variable 'username'

The variable works. Why do I get this warning?

**login.java**

```
package ch.yourclick.zt;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.setAttribute("username", req.getParameter("username"));
        req.setAttribute("password", req.getParameter("password"));
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve variable 'username'` means username is not declared

Comment: @AkashJain so why does it work, if it's not declared?

Comment: intelJ might not have imported the dependency's  at that moment but your compiler will not be effected as the classes are imported during runtime , try cleaning your project it might help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905896/intellij-inspection-gives-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-still-compiles-code here is a similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

**Option 1**

```
<% String username = (String) request.getAttribute("username"); %>
<%= username %>
```

**Option 2**

```
${requestScope.username}
```

Comment: what is requestScope?

Answer (score 1):

May be your login.java you use `sendRedirect` to welcome.jsp page and it lost request scope variable.

```
response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
```

In login.java you need change to this to keep username variable

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

For prevent warning you can update setting for Intellij > Setting > Code Inspection

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html

Comment: Thanks, I did the same but I still get the same warning.

Comment: Where did you set attribute username ? You need add req.setAttribute before forward in doPost

Comment: I have updated my question and posted the whole code.

Comment: In your code you only set attribute for password, need set attribute for username too

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad. Actually it has both, username and password. I have updated the code but the warning stays the same.

Comment: In your browser is it displayed username?

Comment: Yes, it is displayed.

Comment: you can update setting at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/thymeleaf.html

Comment: You can update setting for code inspection like updated answer

Comment: Thanks for that info. I could uncheck `EL Validation in JSP`. Then I wouldn't get any warnings at all. For instance, if I use `${something}` and the variable `something` really doesn't exist, I won't get any warnings.