# Maven java project in Intellij IDEA 2019.3, JDK 11.0.3: Cannot resolve symbol 'java' but still compile

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

What I have:

- Intellij IDEA 2019.3, bundled JDK 11.0.3
- A Maven project with project JDK: the bundled JDK

  My problem: 
  For any `java.` imports I get the error `Cannot resolve symbol ...` **but** I can still compile correctly.
  I'm totally aware that a lot of people already discussed this problem, and of course I have tried all of it:
- Use the dialog 'Setup JDK' a thousand times to set the project JDK again
- Validate that all modules and the project use the correct language level 11
- Invalidate Cache / Restart
- Delete the file `<project name>.iml`
- Delete the `.idea` directory
- Reimport the whole maven project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is connected with the bundled JDK: I have installed manually another JDK 11.0.4, set it as project JDK and now it works