# Unable to download all maven dependencies

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3

I have multi module maven project in intelliJ 2019.3 (Ultimate)

I am not able to get all dependencies after several tries. I tried below solutions as well

[Solution 1](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206903515/comments/206495485)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905896/intellij-inspection-gives-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-still-compiles-code)

I noticed under the Maven tool **same module shows twice** as below

[image]

Not sure that caused the issue here.

Strangely I don't see any red lines in the any of the POMs

Comment: I was managed to get rid of duplicate root by ignoring that `.flattened-pom.xml` via intellij settings>buildTool>Maven>Ignorefiles. Still the dependency download issue is there though

Comment: Can you build from command line Maven?

Comment: @Andrey I get build errors even from command line due to missing dependencies. But why it's not showing any red lines in any of the POM.xml s

Comment: @Andrey Build success via IntelliJ despite missing dependencies under `External Libraries`. So bit confusing

Comment: Finally I resolve those compile errors and app can be run from IDE and command line. But still an't see all the dependencies in POM under the external Libraries in intelliJ

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you can build project from command line Maven and dependencies are downloaded.

In IntelliJ IDEA please try: File | New | Project from Existing Sources action and point to pom.xml file to import project from. Then choose to delete existing project configuration.

Comment: With above suggestion where do you see `Then choose to delete existing project configuration.` option that you mentioned? I did rest of the part but still can't see all POM dependencies under `External Libraries` section.