# Intellij MavenWrapperDownloader.java: Can not resolve symbol error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

**Setup:**

- Intellij IDEA community edition 2020.2
- Spring Bott starter parent: 2.3.5
- Java 11
- WRAPPER_VERSION: 0.5.6
- mvn 2

Hi,
I googled a lot e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905931/9326543) but I just can't fix it.
I created a new mvn spring project with Intellij. When I commit the project I get errors detected by code analyses in class: `MavenWrapperDownloader.java`.
e.g. It reports:

> Cannot resolve symbol String

I tried:

1. invalidate caches and restart
2. delete .idea folder and reimport
3. checked sdk setup
4. mvn reimport
5. mvn clean and then rebuild (while the build is always successful)

I'm pretty new to maven. I guess the scope of the mvn package might be wrong because the build process works as expected.

**UPDATE:**
I reinstallt my openjdk11. No success. Then I found out that my .mvn/wrapper dir is not set as source root. I know that was never the case in my other projects. As a trial I've set my .mvn folder as source root and now the MavenWrapperDownloader.java file is recognized as a java class and the compiler interprets the symbols. But now there is another error. It says I have to define a package name for that class because the class does not have one per default. It is pretty strange to me. I also tried to use another spring boot starter version but nothing changed

When I execute Analyze->inspect code I get the following:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you get that error at version control commit?

Comment: Yes. When I execute commit I get the error that there are 66 issues. When I inspect them besides the warnings there are only "Connot resolve symbol ..." errors

Comment: Please try to delete all SDKs from IDE and install them again.

Comment: Why should this be related to the sdk?

Comment: I did it but nochting changed. See my updated question

Comment: "String" comes from SDK. Is it possible to provide project sample for investigation?

Comment: Yes see my update. When I set this folder as source root, the symbols are resolved properly

Comment: Please share your sample project for investigation.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't. It's a private repo. 
But it relly is a fresh project by spring initilizer created within intellij. Right after it is opened, I execute the commit without any changes.

Comment: Is it possible to check the issue with Ultimate edition (e.g. 2020.3 EAP: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion)?

Comment: I‘m sorry but I‘m bound to community Edition.

Comment: Do you get the same issue with "Analyse | Inspect Code" action?

Comment: When I execute inspect code , I get under Shell script -> mvnw : "Can't follow non-constant source. Use a directive to specify". See my updated question

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: I have the exact same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart fixed it - at least for now.

IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3
Spring Boot Starter Parent 2.4.2
Java 15
Maven 4.0.0
Maven Wrapper 0.5.6

Comment: that's not an answer to the question. As you can see, I've mentioned that I tried this solution. In addtion I reported the error for community edition and not Ultimate. No down vote because it might help others with this setup.

Comment: Sorry, still new here. I just posted it in case it might help others. I would have done it by comment, but my account is not old enough to comment other answers than my own.

Comment: No problem. Welcome on board

Comment: Having the same issue with roughly similar configuration (Intellij CE), Invalidate Caches/Restart didn't make it, but marking the 'wrapper' folder as excluded lifted the blocking error on code analysis/commit.

However, consequences are yet unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to generate your project again with [Spring Starter](https://start.spring.io/).

After you set up everything you need at pom file -> Generate -> Download it.

Open with your IDE and copy-paste all *code sources* which you have already written.