# IntelliJ fails to load JUnit5 after migration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am experimenting what I think to be a purely **Intellij** related issue (though I don't know how to fix it nor where it comes from). I basically followed [this tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/08/migrating-from-junit-4-to-junit-5/) to migrate tests from JUnit 4 to 5.

### Tests after migration

By the end of the migration, I now have the following dependencies in `pom.xml`

```xml
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and the different **Test Classes** now uses

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

### Problem

I keep getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'jupiter'` while running tests in IntelliJ. However, **everything is OK in my CI pipeline** ?!?!? (so probably something wrong in IntelliJ). No matter the fix actions proposed (resp. `Add JUnit 5.4 to classpath` and `Add Maven dependencies`), I keep getting the same. So what's next?

[image]

### Environment

- openjdk11
- IntelliJ 2020.3.1

Interestingly, changes do not seem to be reflected on **cockpit.iml**, for it still contains

```xml
 <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: junit:junit:4.11" level="project" />
```

and no mention of JUnit 5. Are both problems related?

### What I tried

- based on [this documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea), I added `org.junit.platform`:`junit-platform-launcher`
- I tried `File | Invalidate Caches` [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905931/7648881)
- remove `.idea` and `cockpit.iml` to reimport everything.

There is a mismatch somewhere but I can't figure where

Comment: I'm assuming the CI pipeline executes some commands to compile and run these tests. If you do those yourself on your machine does it work? And also verify that these tests are actually getting executed, perhaps add a failing test first.

Comment: if your using maven try to reinstall packages

Comment: I checked: tests are executed in the pipeline and pass. Tests used to work in IntelliJ before the migration. Concerning `mvn test` it passes but I think that IntelliJ use a different java than the java 11 on the rest of my system

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905896/intellij-inspection-gives-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-still-compiles-code

Comment: @Sibin : I tried those

Comment: Its been awhile since I used maven, so your milage may vary, I start by refreshing the build, for gradle intellij shows a little refresh icon in the open code panes, or you can issue a refresh from the maven panel.  If that fails, I would invalidate the caches, if that fails, I would force a restart.  If that fails I would clear JUnit from my .m2 directory and then attempt a rebuild of the project.
Sometimes if you are using something like nexus as a maven proxy it may not have download so you would need to talk to your nexus admin.

Comment: JUnit 5.6.2 is working for me, but I am using gradle and JUnit 5 is being pulled in via a Spring Boot starter.

Comment: Can you build the project by Maven from command line `mvn clean install`? Make sure you have your tests in **src/main/test** directory as **test** Maven scope will only attach test-scoped classes inside this directory by default. Also make sure you have **Reloaded** the Maven project in Maven tool window after you have changed the pom.xml. If problem remains can you provide a sample project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out: a **syntax error** somewhere in `pom.xml` prevented **IntelliJ** from properly downloading new dependencies (or so it seems). The *refresh maven deps* button disappeared after clicking but libraries were not downloaded.

Comment: How did you find out about the syntax error? Were there any errors shown in pom.xml Editor or in Build tool window?

Comment: It was a tricky one, for IntelliJ pointed the error on the `<project>` while, in fact, the problem was that I introduced `${version}` in `<version>`

Comment: Thanks for the information. We will try to make this error more prominent: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-258602

Answer (score 0):

exactly same issue. I added the Junit to Maven pom file and it fixed it.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.13.1