# Cannot find main.iml in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to Intellij IDEA. I recently upgraded Intellij from 2021.1 to 2021.2. After indexing, all the fields and methods are not recognized. When we hover the mouse over the field I get a message stating "cannot resolve symbol". I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39271103/9230036) which says to delete the main.iml. However, I'm not able to find main.iml but <project_name>.iml is present under .idea folder. By deleting the <project_name>.iml the whole project structure is destroyed. Where do I find main.iml file.

PS: Mine is neither a Maven nor a Gradle project. I'm using ANT.

Answer (score 0):

> I found this which says to delete the main.iml. However, I'm not able to find main.iml but <project_name>.iml is present under .idea folder.

main.iml is a project/module name. In your case it will be <project_name>.iml.

> "cannot resolve symbol"

You can try to do:

- `File | Invalidate caches... | Invalidate and Restart`
- Close the project `File | Close Project`
- Close the IDE
- Delete all .iml files and the.idea directory
- Re-import the project into IntelliJ from [Existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project)

Comment: Mine is not a Gradle project as mentioned, I'm using ant as a build tool. Choosing Gradle project is not an option for me. I get an error saying 'settings.gradle(.kts)' is missing when I choose Gradle. Neither is the Eclipse project working for me.