# Spring Boot Application - No option to run

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am fairly new to frameworks in general, so this may just be a really easy fix that I just don't know about. I have been working on this Spring Boot web application for a while using Maven and working in IntelliJ IDEA. I came to work on it today, and suddenly all my classes have this little orange circle next to them instead of the green circle like usual. Also, none of my annotations are appearing yellow like normal, and, worst of all, there are no options to run the application anywhere. I don't understand what happened because everything was working fine last night. Does anyone know what has gone wrong?

I don't know that much about Maven, but I have tried running a clean, which works fine. I have tried restarting IntelliJ, as well as invalidating caches. I also tried going back to my last commit on GitHub, and even that version no longer runs for me. Here is the link on GitHub if anyone wants to look at it: https://github.com/Tyler-Pear/sfg-pet-clinic.

Comment: Please try the following steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/68713145/12844632