# Could not autowire. No Beans of "BoardingPassRepository" found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a basic Repository for my model "BoardingPass".

```
@Repository
public interface BoardingPassRepository extends MongoRepository<BoardingPass, String> {

}
```

When trying to use the Repository, IntelliJ underlines the repository red and displays me "Could not autowire. No Beans of "BoardingPassRepository" found.". I fixed this problem by using @EnableMongoRepository, so now the Application runs, yet IntelliJ still displays this error. How do I correctly fix this problem so that not only the program runs, but also IntelliJ accepts it?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = BoardingPassRepository.class)
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
private BoardingPassRepository repository;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the package of your Main class and BoardingPassRespository interface?

Comment: I guess, your repository class is not getting scan for creating bean in IOC. either repository class package should be same as main class package or repository class package should be a sub-package of main class package.

Comment: Sometimes Intellij just gets confused. Try going through some of the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905896/intellij-inspection-gives-cannot-resolve-symbol-but-still-compiles-code

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was indeed a problem with the ComponentScanning which I solved using @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "Server.repository" })