# IntelliJ import not recognize a java class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just learn IntelliJ as a Eclipse user and created a new projet.

I've a main package com.test where I got the following packages :

- com.test.model
- com.test.repository
- com.test.repository.projection
- com.test.service

Inside my model package I got a PurchaseHistory class.

Into my repository package I got a class that import PurchaseHistory but the class is not recognized what could be wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Please try the following solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/5905931/12844632

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Egor Klepikov it works fine right now.