# IntelliJ IDEA on osx lion - How to setup JSDK?

Tags: java, macos, ide, intellij-idea, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IntelliJ IDEA JDK configuration on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481951/intellij-idea-jdk-configuration-on-mac-os)

I'm currently trying to get IntelliJ to work on my osx lion. But when creating a new project the wizard shows me the following page:

> Please select JSDK for this project
>
> Project JDK
>
> Nothing to show

And no matter where I go with the file browser, I always get "nothing to show". Because of that I can't complete the wizard... (I tried several places I found googling)
(Creating Java apps with Eclipse works fine by the way)

What do I have to do to get this working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, IDEA already preselected the correct directory when adding a new JSDK.