# Why is my random generator code an error?

Tags: intellij-idea

when i wrote "import java.util.Random;" the java was red and said cannot resolve symbol java. Is there something I need to download for that to work?

This is my code from a camp and I put the code on a drive and put it back on my computer. I had to download processing on this computer and i don't know if I have to download anything else.

there are a bunch of errors in my code because of this

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure [JDK is configured](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html) for the project/module.

See also the [getting started document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html).

Comment: Java Development Kit, [there is a link to download in the document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#install-jdk), see my answer.

Comment: i downloaded it and put it in the folder it told me to. im confused on installing it in intellij

Comment: [See here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#change-project-sdk). Click New and specify the installation path of your JDK.

Comment: it said i have no sdk do i need that also?

Comment: i am also on mac

Comment: No, you add a new JDK, then specify the path to JDK as shown on the linked video.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481951/intellij-idea-jdk-configuration-on-mac-os for the macOS example.

Comment: i pressed: 1) new 2) JDK 3) went to the folder 4) pressed on the file 5) clicked "open" and nothing happened...

Comment: it didnt change